# Defining colors for col and bg using two different factors in ggplot2

Tags: r, colors, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to show change in Sensitivity and Selectivity for 13 different programs over 3 generations.  Here's the data for programs 1 and 2, for example:

```
Sensitivity Selectivity Program Generation
0.317       0.347       1       1
0.282       0.301       2       1
0.496       0.118       1       2
0.339       0.176       2       2
0.525       0.050       1       3
0.397       0.131       2       3
```

I want a scatter plot with lines connecting the points for a given program (3 points per program, one for each generation) and different colors for each program, and points with an outline the same color as the line for that program but with fill defined by generation.

Some pairs of points are very close together and the generation points end up overlapping a bit, so it would be clearer if the point outline and fill are mapped together rather than making one layer for the programs and overlaying another layer for the generations.  So I'm using a shape where the outline and fill can be defined (pch=21).  I'm getting close to how I want the plot to look with this:

```
dataset=read.csv("10cmpds_mammal_mean_allgens.csv",h=T)

Generation<-factor(dataset$Generation)
Program<-factor(dataset$Program)

ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=dataset,aes(x=Sensitivity,y=Selectivity,color=factor(Program)),size=1)+
  geom_point(data=dataset, aes(x=Sensitivity, y=Selectivity, color=factor(Program)), pch=21, col=factor(Program), bg=factor(Generation),size=6)+
  scale_color_manual(name="", values=c("#D42515","#D49A95","#DD7310","#F0CD1E","#0FB135","#0B78CC","#679EC9","#353535","#505050","#7B7A7C","#B4B4B4","#8348CF","#A787D1"))
```

This produces the right effect, but I can't figure out how to change the fill colors.  Adding additional color definitions to `scale_color_manual` doesn't affect the fill colors (there are 13 colors listed there because I have 13 programs plotted).  How can I manually define fill colors based on the generation?

Perhaps some sort of interaction (for example, discussed here: [Coloring ggplot by multiple factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277284/coloring-ggplot-by-multiple-factors)) would get us closer, but I don't see exactly how to make that work.

Thanks!

---

Edited to add that a colleague came up with a way to achieve this using the base R package:

```
dataset=read.csv("10cmpds_mammal_mean_allgens.csv",h=T)

color_lines=c("blue", "orange","purple","green","red","gray","black","brown","yellow","tan","aquamarine","gold","purple")

legend_colors=c("bisque", "gray", "black", "blue","orange","purple","green","red","gray","black","brown","yellow","tan","aquamarine","gold","purple")
legend_names=c("Generation 1","Generation 2","Generation 3", "model1","model2","model3","model4","model5","model6","model7","model8","model9","model10","model11","model12","model13")

legend_shapes = c(16,16,16,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15)

plot(1, type="n", xlab="Sensitivity", ylab="Selectivity", xlim=c(0, 0.75), ylim=c(0, 0.75))

for(i in 1:max(dataset[,3])){
  program_select <- which(dataset[,3]==i)
  xvals <- dataset[program_select,1]
  yvals <- dataset[program_select,2]

  lines(xvals,yvals, col=color_lines[i])
  points(xvals,yvals, cex=2, pch=21, col=color_lines[i], bg=c("bisque","grey","black"))
}

legend("topright", legend_names, pch=legend_shapes, col=legend_colors, cex=0.75, x.intersp = 0.7, y.intersp = 0.6)
```

If it's possible I'd still like to produce this in ggplot2, just so that the plot can easily match the style of other plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
ggplot(data = dataset,
       aes(x = Sensitivity, y = Selectivity,
           color = factor(Program),
           fill = factor(Generation),
           group = factor(Program)))+
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 6) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "",
                     values = c("#D42515", "#D49A95", "#DD7310",
                                "#F0CD1E", "#0FB135", "#0B78CC", 
                                "#679EC9", "#353535", "#505050", 
                                "#7B7A7C", "#B4B4B4", "#8348CF", "#A787D1")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("bisque", "grey", "black"))
```

If you specify your aesthetic mappings in the original `ggplot()` call (and your data), you don't need to repeat them for subsequent layers. I used the same colors for fill as you did for color, which is probably a poor choice, but you can change them to the right number/values.

Also worth pointing out that hard-to-remember acronyms like "pch" and "bg" are meaningless in ggplot. "pch" is replaced by `shape`, and "bg" is replaced by `fill` (and "col" by `color`).

Ialsoaddedwhitepsaceasitimprovesreadability.

Using the data you provided in your question, this yields the following plot

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gregor, but this doesn't seem to fix the issue.  The problem is that I need 13 different line/outline colors (one for each program) but only 3 different fill colors (one for each generation).  So within a given program's line, there will be 3 points, each of which will have a unique color to signify generation 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Try now. I hadn't seen at the top where you specified that there were only 3 generations. You just need to make the number of values in your `fill` scale equal the number of necessary values. I switched to the colors from your edits.

Comment: Ah, there it is.  Thank you!